# Blazor: value updated by component - page not updated

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm facing a strange behaviour in Blazor, and I'd like to understand exactly what is going on.

I have this page:

```
@page "/"

<div>IsSet: @myObj.IsSet</div>

<MyComponent Param1="myObj" OnSet="OnSetHandler"></MyComponent>

@code
{
    private MyClass myObj = new();

    private void OnSetHandler()
    {
        /* this is actually an empty function */
    }
}
```

This is `MyComponent`:

```
<hr />

<h6>MyComponent</h6>

<div>IsSet: @Param1.IsSet</div>
<button type="button" @onclick="SetVal">Set value</button>

<hr />

@code {

    [Parameter] public MyClass Param1 { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnSet { get; set; }

    private async Task SetVal()
    {
        Param1.IsSet = true;

        if (OnSet.HasDelegate) await OnSet.InvokeAsync();
    }

}
```

and `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool IsSet { get; set; }
}
```

In this case the component instance has an handler for OnSet, and the page behaves as expected - this is the page when I click on the button:

```
IsSet: True
----------------------------------------
MyComponent
IsSet: True
----------------------------------------

[ Set value ]
```

As soon as I remove the OnSet handler in the page (`<MyComponent Param1="myObj"></MyComponent>`), this is what happens when I click the button:

```
IsSet: False
----------------------------------------
MyComponent
IsSet: True
----------------------------------------
```

This seems strange to me because the handler, when specified, is actually an empty function.

I also tried to add `StateHasChanged` in the component:

```
private async Task SetVal()
{
    Param1.IsSet = true;

    if (OnSet.HasDelegate) await OnSet.InvokeAsync();

    StateHasChanged();
}
```

but this has no effect.

This also happens if I specity `OnSet="default(Action)"`.

Comment: You don't have to check `OnSet.HasDelegate`

Comment: @BrianParker could you please elaborate a bit more? I tried ``EventCallback<MyClass> Param1Changed`` and ``EventCallback Param1Changed`` but none of them worked. Should I invoke it (I tried but nothing changed)?

Comment: @BrianParker: two way binding is not valid here, since the parameter value does not change (it's a complex object that changes internally)

Comment: @BrianParker: In the REPL, the main component is not rerendered. It would if you actually used two way binding `@bind-Param1="myObj"`, but that's not how it is supposed to be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, the containing component doesn't rerender automatically, when something happens in a child component.

This is expected and documented behaviour, see the [blazor docs -> components -> rendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Component rerenders when:

- After applying an updated set of parameters from a parent component.
- After applying an updated value for a cascading parameter.
- **After notification of an event and invoking one of its own event handlers.**
- After a call to its own `StateHasChanged` method

In your case, when you click MyComponent's button, the event handler rerenders `MyComponent`.
The containing page is rerendered only when there is the event handler for `MyComponent.OnSet`.

---

> The problem with this approach is that one should take care of every callback provided by the component. I hoped to find a way to automatically notify the containing page of the change.

There are several ways of notifying the containing page.

1. You can create one universal `EventCallback` in the child component, e.g. `OnChange`, which would be called each time anything has changed
2. Your `MyClass` can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and your containing page can call `StateHasChanged()` manually in `PropertyChanged` event handler
3. You can call `EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged()` in child component and `StateHasChanged()` manually in `EditContext.OnFieldChanged` eventhandler in Containing page

---

**A side note:**

Two way binding like `@bind-SomeProperty="..."` does update the containing component because it creates the event handler for you. It is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: [Very Polite] Good answer.  However, "After notification of an event and invoking one of its own event handlers." is a behaviour built into `ComponentBase` not all Components.  In the MS docs page you referenced the heading is "Rendering conventions for ComponentBase".  Picky I know, it's a pet topic of mine, but Component != ComponentBase!  Which is why the MS documentation now specifically says ComponentBase.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis: Thanks for mentioning this. For sake of simplicity I've omitted this.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to understand exactly what is going on

You need a StatehasChanged() to happen on the page. Attaching an (empty) method to the EventCallback will do that.

> I also tried to add StateHasChanged in the component:

The component is already re-rendered because of the `@onclick`, but that doesn't cascade 'up' to the parent.

The empty method is an acceptable workaround.
The shortest form is `OnSet="() => {}"`

Comment: The problem with this approach is that one should take care of every callback provided by the component. I hoped to find a way to automatically notify the containing page of the change. The comment in the question from @BrianPaker seems to go this way but I tried it and it didn't work (maybe my fault).

Comment: Answer upvoted. Explanation is valid as well as advice "The empty method is an acceptable workaround". @BrianPaker's comment is not valid in this context

Answer (score 0):

This answer is intended to add more detail to the other two answers.

All Razor Components inherit from `ComponentBase` by default.

`ComponentBase` implements the `IHandleEvent` interface which defines a custom event handler that the Renderer calls for all UI events associated with the component.

The implementation looks like this.

```cs
Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
{
    var task = callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
    var shouldAwaitTask = task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion &&
        task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled;

    // After each event, we synchronously re-render (unless !ShouldRender())
    // This just saves the developer the trouble of putting "StateHasChanged();"
    // at the end of every event callback.
    StateHasChanged();

    return shouldAwaitTask ?
        CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(task) :
        Task.CompletedTask;
}

// Broken out as used elsewhere in the component lifecycle
private async Task CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
{
    try
    {
        await task;
    }
    catch // avoiding exception filters for AOT runtime support
    {
        // Ignore exceptions from task cancellations, but don't bother issuing a state change.
        if (task.IsCanceled)
            return;

        throw;
    }
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

All UI events driven by the Renderer are handled by the handler.  All non UI events, such as those raised by event handlers and normal `Action` and `Func` callbacks are invoked directly.

Try adding this to your component to see what happens.

```cs
@implements IHandleEvent

//...
@code {
    public async Task HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
    {
        await callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
        // StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```